# How Do I Pass The Package To RemoteView in Android?

Tags: android, view, package

Me Doing "edu.sju.BlackJack"  Is not causing updates that are later called to occur.
I reference the layout correctly and the calls that are supposed to update it are correct, so what do I put in for the package name?

I should add that my package name according to the manifest is the above.
This is the code I have now which currently doesn't update the screen (or i'm guessing change the value correctly).

RemoteViews name = new RemoteViews("edu.sju.BlackJack", R.layout.play_screen);

If that's not it.. would it then be this code?

name.setTextViewText(R.id.Dealer_Total, "0");

Dealer_Total is the id for the TextView that I want to change.. however again the Change is not occurring.

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance.

Here is the whole of my code that i'm talking about,  first Playscreen.java

```
package edu.sju.BlackJack;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import java.util.*;


public class PlayScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    GameEngine Engine = new GameEngine();
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.play_screen);
        TextView TextDealer =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Dealer_Total); 
        Engine.setView(TextDealer);
        //Set up click listeners for all the buttons
        View hitButton = findViewById(R.id.hit_button);
        hitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View standButton = findViewById(R.id.stand_button);
        standButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        //new preplay button (ML 10/24/10)
        View prePlayButton = findViewById(R.id.prePlay_button);
        prePlayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        Thread thread = new Thread(Engine);
        thread.start();


    }   

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.prePlay_button:
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                System.out.println("Working?");
                Engine.setGameStart(1);
                break;
            case R.id.hit_button:
                Engine.gameHit(1);
                break;
            case R.id.stand_button:
                Engine.gameStand(1);
                break;
        }

            // More buttons go here (if any) ...    
        }
}
```

---

**Now here's the GameEngine Thread**
Not the Whole of it,  just enough so you get the idea

---

```
package edu.sju.BlackJack;

import java.util.Random;

import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GameEngine   implements Runnable {
    static int playerCount = 0;    //keep record of which cards to change for player when hit is selected
    static int dealerCount = 0;    //keep record of which cards to change for dealer when dealer hits
    static int win = 0;     //keeps record of wins  (JV 10/01/10)
    static int lose = 0;    //keeps record of loss  (JV 10/01/10)
    static int hit = 0;     //let's engine know if hit button was selected (0 means it has not)
    static int stand = 0;    //let's engine know if stand button was selected (0 means it has not)
    static int playerTotal = 0; //tells player's total (JV 10/01/10)
    static int dealerTotal = 0; //tells dealer's total (JV 10/01/10)
    static int playerTurn = 0;  //activates buttons so that they do actions when clicked (as it's players turn)
    static int startGame = 0; //starts the game when the start game button is pressed
    TextView TextDealer;
    RemoteViews name = new RemoteViews("edu.sju.BlackJack", R.layout.play_screen);


public void run() {
    name.setTextViewText(R.id.Dealer_Total, "0");
    //main();
}

public void setView(TextView a)
{
TextDealer = a;
}

public void setGameStart(int i)
{
    startGame = i;
}

public void gameHit(int i)
{
    if(playerTurn == 1)
    hit = 1;
}

public void gameStand(int i)
{
    if(playerTurn == 1)
    stand = 1;
}


public void main()

    {//Start Game
        Deck mainDeck = new Deck();
        fillDeck(mainDeck);

        //TextView TextPlayer =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Player_Total); 
        //TextDealer.setText("" + dealerTotal);
        //TextPlayer.setText("" + playerTotal);

        while(true)
        {
            if(startGame == 1)
            {

                if(mainDeck.getList().size() < 15){
                    mainDeck = emptyDeck();
                    fillDeck(mainDeck);
                    }  

                //RESET CARD VIEWS TO DEFAULT
                //RESET DEALERCARD AND PLAYERCARD TOTALS TO 0
                dealerTotal = 0;
                playerTotal = 0;
                playerCount = 0;
                dealerCount = 0;

                //playHand(mainDeck);

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please vote this if you don't know,  I really need it answered asap.  Thanks again in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever your problem is, I don't think it is what you think it is. If your layout is appearing in the app widget, then the package name is being handled properly. If the update (your `setTextViewText()` call) is not having an effect, then either `R.layout.play_screen` does not have `R.id.Dealer_Total` or you are not sending over a `RemoteViews` that contains the `setTextViewText()` instructions.

Comment: Wait, does remote views have to used by widgets? (My playscreen.java class just contains the layout but isn't a "widget" in and of itself).   It's also what is displaying the screen and calling the thread GameEngine which needs to change the stuff.

Comment: I really hate the auto enter...  R.layout.play_screen does contain R.id.Dealer_Total (Eclipse accesses all my views and gives it to me as options when I'm putting setTextViewText() so it appears to be accessing the layout fine)...   I only have the RemoteViews name and again that's the only thing i'm "sending" so I don't believe it's that either.

Comment: @John V: Sorry, I have only used RemoteViews in the context of app widgets so far.

Comment: is there any other way to edit my views from game engine, besides having it directly recieve the views and catching an exception that gets thrown and ignoring it which says  ERROR/AndroidRuntime(653): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: @John V: Use `AsyncTask`, or a `Handler`, or `runOnUiThread()`, or `post()`. `RemoteViews` are not for normal applications.

Comment: Alright time to learn one of those now and hope for success.  Thank you very much for the help! :)

Comment: Wait with all these methods,  I'm still not going to be able to access the views into GameEngine... am i?

Comment: @John V: Why does `GameEngine` even exist?

Comment: To Hold the totals for the players and "play" the game

Comment: Basically the UI just holds the button interactions, and I need GameEngine to run the game continously and hold the values and display them as they change

Comment: Because If I have GameEngine inside the UI thread it just freezes upon execution as the thread would never die*

Comment: @John V: I am still at a loss as to why a card game needs a persistent background thread, particularly blackjack. You deal. Player taps "hit me", you respond. Player taps "split", you respond. Etc. Classic event-driven programming, what we've done for decades. No background threads required. Particularly, you do not need a background thread that is in a tight infinite loop burning CPU and battery, as you have it implemented presently.

Comment: I need to keep the methods alive in order to preserve deck data.  I think my method has been wrong from the get-go, but we've found "workarounds" until realizing hey we can't view stuff.

Comment: I'm more of an object oriented programmer : (.... this object deals with all this.. that object does some of that... etc

Comment: @John V: Which is why I don't like treating threads as objects.

Comment: But even if I treated the object as an Object (which I did initially)  I still ran into the freezing problem as that object was accessed from the UI

Comment: @John V: "But even if I treated the object as an Object (which I did initially) I still ran into the freezing problem as that object was accessed from the UI" -- then you've screwed up something else somewhere else.

Comment: The Application Not Responding Error, because the method would not end in 3 seconds or what not that is used from the object and called from playscreen.

Comment: Like in the above code,  say I did engine.main() when start button was pressed,  it would freeze.  get my meaning?

Comment: @John V: I got your meaning originally. You need to learn event-driven programming and get rid of your infinite loop.

Comment: If it takes more than 3 seconds to do ANY calculation in a  card game, you have implemented your algorithms horribly.

Comment: it was all while loops.. so that it'd be a process... ala wait for game start to be pressed, deal the two cards, wait for hit or stand to be pressed, if hit is pressed add a card etc... if stand is pressed do dealer ai.  then rinse and repeat.

Comment: because i still don't see how displaying each card when it's being "created" into the game is going to be possible (especially for dealer a.i) since literally there is no input by the player after that and the dealer a.i would need to keep going until either it busted or had >= 17